# Yourkit cpu sampling

Tags: yourkit

sorry I can't paste the code here but I'm using yourkit to cpu sampling for my app and I see the following:

11.0.10 - 120.347: warning: NULL class name

11.0.10 - 120.348: java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH

11.0.10 - 153.824: Snapshot captured: RealtimeApp-2017-12-22-1.snapshot

11.0.10 - 1728.006: java.util.ArrayList$1 SAME

How can I find out what this ArrayList is about?

Separately, when I loaded the snapshot in yourkit and I saw this

[image: Yourkit CPU]
This grey region has no information whatsoever. How can I find out what it's doing.

In particular, in my log, I can see there's a 10 second window where there's simply no logging... (I used log4j2 and Discard strategy.. so I'm suspecting my log4j2 is getting overflowed but I haven't found a way to prove it)

Thanks!!

Comment: More information please. What does the application do? What does the Log4j2 configuration look like? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I think all my problems came from here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971267/chronicle-queue-log4j2-async-logger/47972404#47972404